# Two Asynctask and 1 splashscreen

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Hi guys i have 2 asynctask and 1 splashscreen. I want execute 2 asynctask in splashscreen...
when 2 threads asynctask are  finish show my app...

### arrivi.java

```
public class arrivi extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View arrivi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.arrivi, container, false); 


      new MyTask().execute("");
```

### partenze.java

```
 public class partenze extends Fragment {

   @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View partenze = inflater.inflate(R.layout.partenze, container, false);
       new MyTask().execute("");
          return partenze;
   }
```

### splashscreen:

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

private boolean mIsBackButtonPressed;
private static final int SPLASH_DURATION = 6000; //6 seconds
private Handler myhandler;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);

//CONTROLLO CONNESSIONE
    if (!isOnline()){
        try {
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

            alertDialog.setTitle("Info");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Connessione Internet non disponibile.");
            alertDialog.setButton("Esci", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }                       

            });
            alertDialog.show();
        }
        catch(Exception e) { }
    }
    // FINE CONTROLLO CONNESSIONE

    myhandler = new Handler();

    // run a thread to start the home screen
    myhandler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
           finish();

           if (!mIsBackButtonPressed)
           {
                // start the home activity 
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                SplashScreen.this.startActivity(intent);
           }

        }

    }, SPLASH_DURATION); 
}


 //handle back button press
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() 
 {
    mIsBackButtonPressed = true;
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

can you help me please? 
what is the easiest method?
i Want show my MainActivity when asynctask's finished... thank you!

Comment: you could use a `TimerTask` or something to check on a repeated time period if your tasks have finished and start your app.

Comment: Why you call MyTask  inside fragments and not in screensplash?

Comment: When i call myTask into Splashscreen.. i have NullPointerException - in arrivi.java:  protected void onPreExecute() {
            prog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity()); - in splashscreen:         new arrivi().new MyTask().execute();

Comment: @Xenione is commented in my code

Answer (score 0):

1. Maintain two booleans in your splash screen class, one for each async task.
2. Override onPostExecute() method for each asynctask and update the state of booleans through this method. This way you can check if async task is finished.
3. Keep checking in while loop for those boolean.

   ```
   do {
        // Do nothing. Just wait untill both booleans are set. 
   } while(bool1 && bool2);
   // Execute your code which you want to execute after finishing both async tasks
   ```

Comment: Yes... but i get a nullpointer if i call myTask into splashscreen.java
        new arrivi().new MyTask().execute();
and into the asynctask have:             prog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

Comment: What is the stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask provide execution some code, when it finished. 
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29)

you can send info about finished task to method (ex. controllerOfTaskExecution), which will be start your MainActivity.